# How to log with stacktrace and not show in release version?

Tags: dart

I tried to handle exception like this.

```
try {
  // some functions that likely to throw error
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

but this `print(e)` didn't tell me where error come from, it only tell me what error is.

I want to know where error come from and have links that navigate to that line. like this
[image]

I also don't want to log on release version, so `print` is not my anwser.

Can you please give any example on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of options here depending on whether or not you'll want to be able to control logging output throughout your application or if this is a one-off situation.

**Solution 1: make use of asserts**

In Dart, `assert(...)` invocations are only included in debug builds (e.g. processes started via `flutter run` or `dart --enable-asserts foo.dart`). You can utilize this fact to conditionally execute code depending on whether or not your program is running in release by doing the following:

```
assert(() {
  print('debug-only logging');
}());
```

**Solution 2: use `package:logging`**

A more general solution is to use [`package:logging`](https://pub.dev/packages/logging) to set up a global `Logger` instance and then only log through that interface. This package lets you write logs with different verbosities and the `level` property of `Logger` can be used to determine which log levels are actually printed. This can be combined with solution #1 to conditionally enable logging throughout the application only while debugging:

```dart
void main() {
  // Disable logs by default.
  myLogger.level = Level.OFF;
  assert(() {
    // Enable logs in debug mode.
    myLogger.level = Level.ALL;
  }());

  // Your logic here
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I think is much better than `debugPrint` and `log`. But can I ask how to log stacktrace?

Comment: All of the logging methods on `Logger` take optional positional parameters for `error` and `stackTrace`.  Take a look at the [documentation for the generic `log` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/logging/latest/logging/Logger/log.html) for more details.